# Angle of an arc in a circle

Tags: circles

A mathematics book on circle states one of the properties of circle as follows :
"angle formed by two chords intersecting in a circle is equal in degrees to one-half the sum of its intercepted arcs."
What does that mean? How is it derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is a snapshot from a text I am using. I hope this answer is clear.
Any good geometry book will include this.